# Changing Bootstrap-Table Child Row Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to figure out how to modify what data is shown in the child row of the table I have using Bootstrap-Table. I've searched the documentation here https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcome.html and haven't found any valuable information and nor have I had any luck through past posts here or on google.

Table:

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-show-fullscreen="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
  data-detail-view="true"
  data-show-export="true"
  data-click-to-select="true"
  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
  data-minimum-count-columns="2"
  data-show-pagination-switch="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-id-field="id"
  data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
  data-side-pagination="server"
   data-url="ajax.php" 
  data-response-handler="responseHandler" >
          <thead>
        <tr>
                                    <tr>

                                    <th data-field="id">ID</th>
                                      <th data-field="name">Vendor</th>
                                      <th data-field="company">Company</th>
                                      <th data-field="type">Type</th>
                                      <th data-field="status">Status</th>
                                      <th data-field="owner">Owner</th>
</tr>



        </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

```
<script>
  var $table = $('#table')
  var $remove = $('#remove')
  var selections = []
    document.getElementById("Add").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "new.php";
    };

  function getIdSelections() {
    return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
      return row.id
    })
  }

  function responseHandler(res) {


    $.each (res.rows, function (i, row) {
      row.state = $.inArray(row.id, selections) !== -1
    })
    return res
  }

  function detailFormatter(index, row) {
    var html = []
    $.each(row, function (key, value) {
      html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>')
    })
    return html.join('')
  }

  function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [

      '<a class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Remove">',
      '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
      '</a>'
    ].join('')
  }

  window.operateEvents = {
    'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
      alert('You click like action, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row))
    },
    'click .remove': function (e, value, row, index) {
      $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: [row.id]
      })
    }
  }

  function totalTextFormatter(data) {
    return 'Total'
  }

  function totalNameFormatter(data) {
    return data.length
  }

  function totalPriceFormatter(data) {
    var field = this.field
    return '$' + data.map(function (row) {
      return +row[field].substring(1)
    }).reduce(function (sum, i) {
      return sum + i
    }, 0)
  }

  function initTable() {
    $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({

      height: 700,
      locale: $('#locale').val(),
      columns: [
        [{
          field: 'state',
          checkbox: true,
          rowspan: 2,
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle'
        }, {
          title: '',
          rowspan: 1,
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
        }, {
          title: 'Vendor Details',
          colspan: 5,
          align: 'center'
        }],
        [{
          field: 'name',
          title: 'Vendor',
          sortable: true,
          footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
          align: 'center',

        }, {
          field: 'company',
          title: 'Company',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },{
          field: 'status',
          title: 'Status',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },
        {
          field: 'owner',
          title: 'Owner',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        }, {
          field: 'dept',
          title: 'Department',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
        },
        {
          field: 'operate',
          title: 'Operations',
          align: 'center',
          clickToSelect: false,
          events: window.operateEvents,
          formatter: operateFormatter
        },



        ]
      ]
    })
    $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
      'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table',
    function () {
      $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length)

      // save your data, here just save the current page
      selections = getIdSelections()
      // push or splice the selections if you want to save all data selections
    })
    $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
      console.log(name, args)
    })
    $remove.click(function () {
      var ids = getIdSelections()
      $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: ids
      })
      $remove.prop('disabled', true)
    })
  }

  $(function() {
    initTable()

    $('#locale').change(initTable)
  })
</script>
```